# UWP - Can't use 10.0.10586.212 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sdk, uwp

I have a problem with VS 2015 and a UWP project. I uninstalled and reinstalled yesterday my VS 2015 Community (so, the latest, in Update 3) and, I had a project which contained references to 10.0.10586.0 sdk. This sdk was uninstalled with VS 2015.

When I opened the project this morning, obviously, it didn't compile because of the absence of the sdk. But I have the 2 other versions of the sdk installed (i.e. 10.0.10586.15 and 10.0.10586.212), so, I modified the csproj for targeting the 212 version:

```
<TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586.212</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
<SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.10586.212">
  <Name>Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP</Name>
</SDKReference>
```

Now, VS 2015 doesn't want to load the project anymore and propose me instead to update the sdk... to the 212 version. That I have...

[image: 10.0.10586.212 version installed]

It doesn't me bother downloading the 10.0.10586.0 version, but I can't find it anywhere, Microsoft only proposing the 212 version in the [sdk archives](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).

Is someone already had the same issue ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Community installs the 10.0.10586.0 SDK. If it didn't, it's probably due to a failed uninstall. You can try the [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases) before re-installing VS 2015, to get back into business. Keep in mind, though, that the Visual Studio Uninstaller also removes VS 2013, if that is installed as well.

Comment: Strange, I uninstalled VS 2015 from the apps & programs page. I will try with your link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I uninstalled via the Visual Studio Uninstaller, and it cleaned very well all tracks of VS 2013 and VS 2015 installations. When I reinstalled VS 2015 and launched my project, I still had error with the 10.0.10586.0. In fact, it was the Mobile Extensions for UWP that didn't exist in 10586, but in 10240. So I replaced the 10586 inexistent target with the 10240 and it worked. Thanks for the tip @IInspectable.